# Specifying extras axis in settings in sbt's shell or command line?

Tags: scala, sbt

We use the extras axis to scope keys in our sbt project ([Scala.js](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js) project). We wanted to use the extra axis (in the [Scala.js](https://github.com/gzm0/scala-js/blob/backup/sbt-wiring/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/scala/scalajs/sbtplugin/ScalaJSPlugin.scala) sbt plugin) to provide different `fullClasspath` to runners and test frameworks. Our compilation pipeline has multiple stages and we would like to be able to execute after each stage.

However, I am unable to specify the extras scope on the command line.

If I list something that uses the extras axis (we use the key `stage`) as dependency, sbt will use the following syntax:

```
helloworld/compile:run::fullClasspath(stage: scala.scalajs.sbtplugin.PreoptStage$@5a96721d)
```

However, I am unable to show this value / use the scoped key:

```
show helloworld/compile:run::fullClasspath(stage: PreoptStage)
[error] Expected key
[error] Expected end of input.
[error] Expected whitespace character
[error] show helloworld/compile:run::fullClasspath(stage: PreoptStage)
```

How do I have to write the scope specification? (Note that [sbt parser code](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13.1/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Act.scala#L153) strongly suggests that this is actually supported).

[Some code](https://github.com/gzm0/scala-js/blob/backup/sbt-wiring/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/scala/scalajs/sbtplugin/ScalaJSPlugin.scala) we tested with (look at history to see what happened).

Comment: I'd open a bug report.  I was actually unaware of anyone using the "extra" axis yet.  Can you also give us your use case?

Comment: We wanted to use the extra axis (in the Scala.js sbt plugin) to provide different `fullClasspath`s to runners and test frameworks. Our compilation pipeline has multiple stages and we would like to be able to execute after each stage. However, we have found that the extra axis doesn't work as expected (or not at all). Therefore we have decided to use dummy tasks to re-wire the classpath (`compile:preoptStage::run`).

Comment: Yeah, "extra" axis exists as a "in case we need it we won't break binary compatibility" thing, but I'm not sure it's well tested at all.  I've even debated removing/deprecating it in the future.

Comment: I'd love to help with your use case though.    It sounds like you're doing some kind of multi-stage build with a command?   Did you know you can inject settings before you run tasks?

Comment: @jsuereth *"inject settings before running tasks"* is so common and natural in sbt that when gzm0 asked about *"the extras axis to scope keys in our SBT project"*, I doubt he didn't know about the feature (or it's me to misunderstood your words which is the main reason I'm writing it hoping to learn sbt better).

Comment: @jsuereth What do you mean by inject settings before running a task?